# Is there a "right" answer to Quick Time Events?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Every so often, there will be Quick Time Events (*QTEs*) that will occur and require an answer to be selected. These *QTEs* will have either three or four answers, depending on the situation, and different dialogs will take place based on the answer.

One instance is when you are touring Lestalum with Iris and *QTEs* are shown a few times. Every time I selected an answer, Noctis gained anywhere between 250 - 500 XP. Another instance was when you are heading towards the meteor and there was a *QTE* for deciding who was driving. I selected an answer and Ignis gained 500 XP.

Since different answers appear to give different characters XP, is there an overall "right" answer to these *QTEs*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "right".

If you mean "most rewards," then *yes*, there are right answers to these dialogues.

From [this site](http://gematsu.com/2016/07/final-fantasy-xv-details-ravus-iris-dialogue-choices-shops):

> During the story and on your journey, there will be conversations that require you to select an answer from multiple responses. How the conversation plays out and the contents of the parameters you obtain will change based on your response.

I've noticed that when I make choices that are favorable to the people I'm talking to, I get a pretty good amount of experience.

[Here](http://www.itechpost.com/articles/60654/20161201/final-fantasy-xv-guide-how-to-farm-ap-fast.htm) is another site that mentions different rewards for dialogue choices:

> Some other things that you can do for instant APs in Final Fantasy are going into combat training, finishing a quest, performing combat challenges and doing beneficial dialogues choices.

Comment: I used right loosely (hence quotes) meaning it could go either way. Thanks for the swift response!

Comment: QTE in FF15 are a multifaceted thing. First they shape the character of the characters. Second, they are part of a reward system for opting "in" to giving the character a feel as presented or intended by the character designer. The down-side is that more often than not, its a conversation rail with an obviousness wherein you give a suboptimal answer, you get a suboptimal reward. However, in most cases, the QTE in FF15 is simply to make you engage with the party as a balance to the banter and back-chatter happening; it gives a degree of life to the overall game.